# DHCP option 43 on switch Dell PowerConnect 5500

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, dhcp-server, dell-powerconnect

I have Dell PowerConnect 5524.

Put

```
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 hex f104ac1338fa
```

got

```
Option code 43 is not a valid HEX string.
```

Strange. Its worked ok for me on Cisco device. Looking at User Guide:

> hex hex-string—Specifies dotted hexadecimal data: Each byte in
>   hexadecimal character strings is two hexadecimal digits. Bytes are
>   separated by a period or colon

Trying

```
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 
  ip-list              Specify an IP address list.
  POSITIVE INTEGER     Specify the DHCP option code number
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 
  ascii                ASCII.
  hex                  Specify Option type as Hexadecimal.
  ip                   Specify Option type as IP address.
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 hex 
  WORD                 Specify Option type as Hexadecimal.
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 hex f1.04.ac.13.38.fa
Option code 43 is not a valid HEX string.
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 hex f1:04:ac:13:38:fa
Option code 43 is not a valid HEX string.
```

Question - how do i configure option 43 on this switch?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably like a MAC address: `option 43 hex f104.ac13.38fa`

Comment: Got the same error message

Comment: Please never  crosspost. http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28456/dhcp-option-43-on-switch-dell-powerconnect-5500